# Display figure and then change it randomly every 5 seconds (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I'd like to display a random number between 1000 and 2000 every 5 seconds.

I manged to do it with javascriptMath random() and setInterval BUT I have a  problem: on page load, the first number only appears after 5 seconds so the web visitors see nothing.

I'd like the first number to appear straight from the very first second and then wait for 5 second and get the second number then 5 seconds wait the third number, and so on...

```
<div id="my_number"></div>

setInterval(function() {
    var number = 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    $('#my_number').text(number);
  },
  5000); // every 5 seconds
```

How can I display right away a number and then trigger this 5-sec loop of random numbers?

Thanks

Comment: Just create a function that's trigger on page load, it can show the message and then start the interval

Comment: i'm a beginner in javascript: could you be more explicit in your answer. I don't know how to do what you suggest. sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it

```
function loadRandom() {
     var number = 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
      $('#my_number').text(number);
}

loadRandom(); // for initial display

setInterval(function() {
     loadRandom(); // it excutes every 5sec
  },5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not display a random number on page load?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //set your first random number here!
});
```

You can even take it a step further and set your interval in the page load as well (as per alejandro-ba's suggestion):

```
function someRandom() {
    var number = 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    $('#my_number').text(number);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    someRandom();
    setInterval(function() {
        someRandom();
    },5000);
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, had to give the points to jqueryking as he answered first